# Postgres inet array contains a single ip

Tags: postgresql, address

Requirement: user can add single ips or ip address ranges to a database table(for example permissions table having ipAddresses of `inet[]` type).  I need to query that a single ip is contained in the array of ipAddresses field which can be array of ip addresses or ip address ranges or both. I have tried to add where query like this:

```
WHERE "ipAddresses" @> '192.168.1.5'::inet
```

and also like this

```
WHERE "ipAddresses" >> '192.168.1.5'::inet
```

but no luck.
Thanks in advance.

```
id          uuid      NOT NULL  gen_random_uuid()
permissions uuid[]      
ipAddresses inet[]      
createdAt   timestamp with time zone        now()
updatedAt   timestamp with time zone        now()
```

source: [pg array functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html) and
[pg network address functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-net.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While [McNets's solutions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/180431/6219) would also work, it's possibly the easiest to use [`ANY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN21104) with an operator, in this case equality:

```
SELECT '10.10.10.10' = ANY ('{10.10.10.10, 10.10.10.20}'::inet[]);
```

The background is that an `inet` array is no different from any other array type in this regard - `ANY` will work with any boolean-returning operator that is defined on the base type.

The above applies to equality of single IP addresses.  If you need to match a single IP against a range, you'll need the `<<=` operator instead of `=`:

```
SELECT '10.10.10.10'::inet <<= ANY ('{10.10.10.10, 10.10.10.20}'::inet[]);

 ?column? 
──────────
 t

SELECT '10.10.10.10'::inet <<= ANY ('{10.10.10.0/28, 10.10.10.20}'::inet[]);

 ?column? 
──────────
 t
```

In your case, the solution would look like

```
WHERE '192.168.1.5' <<= ANY ("ipAddresses")
```

The performance of this can be poor for the lack of really efficient indexing.  To address this, see the suggestion in McNets's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let me know if this answer can helps you, I've set up next sample on dbfiddle.uk.

> ```
> create table myt 
> (
> id          uuid      NOT NULL,
> ipAddresses inet[],      
> createdAt   timestamp with time zone,
> updatedAt   timestamp with time zone
> );
> ```

> ```
> insert into myt values
> ('0e37df36-f698-11e6-8dd4-cb9ced3df976'::uuid, array['10.0.0/24','20.0.0.1']::inet[], now(), now()),
> ('0e37df36-f698-11e6-8dd4-cb9ced3df977'::uuid, array['10.0.0.2','20.0.0.2']::inet[], now(), now()),
> ('0e37df36-f698-11e6-8dd4-cb9ced3df978'::uuid, array['10.0.0.4','20.0.0.3']::inet[], now(), now()),
> ('0e37df36-f698-11e6-8dd4-cb9ced3df979'::uuid, array['10.0.0.4']::inet[], now(), now())
> ;
> ```

I'm not really good using arrays, neither on postgres, but as far as you are querying an array, you should use {} to compare elements of an array.

> ```
> select *
> from   myt
> where  ipaddresses @> '{10.0.0.4}'
> ```
>
> ```
> id                                   | ipaddresses         | createdat                     | updatedat                    
> :----------------------------------- | :------------------ | :---------------------------- | :----------------------------
> 0e37df36-f698-11e6-8dd4-cb9ced3df978 | {10.0.0.4,20.0.0.3} | 2017-07-21 11:06:04.547226+01 | 2017-07-21 11:06:04.547226+01
> 0e37df36-f698-11e6-8dd4-cb9ced3df979 | {10.0.0.4}          | 2017-07-21 11:06:04.547226+01 | 2017-07-21 11:06:04.547226+01
> ```

If you are looking if an ip range contains an specific IP, I think you should unnest array elements and then use >> operator.

> ```
> select * 
> from (select id, unnest(ipaddresses) ip
>       from   myt) t1
> where t1.ip::inet >> '10.0.0.4'::inet
> ```
>
> ```
> id                                   | ip         
> :----------------------------------- | :----------
> 0e37df36-f698-11e6-8dd4-cb9ced3df976 | 10.0.0.0/24
> ```

Additionaly let me suggest you to have a look at **[ip4r](https://github.com/RhodiumToad/ip4r)** module.

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=7f6f721bf38ca56bc4a4dd15a4f3d2da)*